# ggplot: Create a new geom based on the combination of two geoms

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two geoms, for instance `geom_smooth` and `geom_point`. I would like to create a new separate geom, `geom_smoothpoint`, which would draw the two aforementioned geoms.

I would like this:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_smoothpoint()
```

to give the same results as below:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
```

[image]

I have tried combining these two:

```
geom_smoothpoint <- function(){
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method="lm")
}
```

But it doesn't really work. It seems that I must combine `ggproto` objects, but I am not sure how. Is there any simple way of combining two geoms into one? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could of course write your own `geom` but this is an absolute overkill. It is much easier to return a list in your function which you can conveniently add to your plot:

```
geom_smoothpoint <- function() {
   list(geom_point(), geom_smooth(method = "lm"))
}

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Width)) +
   geom_smoothpoint()
```